# Using props in a function which is not a component in react

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, redux, state, react-props

So, say for example my code looks something like this:

```
class DoSomething extends Component{
  function1(var1, var2){
    return var1 * var2 / this.props.var3
  }

  render(){
    <div>{function1(10, 20)}</div>
  }
}
```

I would like to abstract function1 into its own file and import it but I would still like it to have access to this component's (or redux's) props / state.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this? Sorry if this question is really whishy, washy.

Comment: what do you actually want to do with function1?

Comment: I want to move it into its own file then export it and import it into my DoSonething component.

Comment: I gave an explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Non React example for demo purposes

```js
const func1 = function(var1, var2) {
  return var1 * var2 / this.props.var3
}

class DoSomething {
  constructor() {
    //fake props for demo,  wouldn't need this in React Component 
    this.props = {var3: 3};
    // assign an internal version of func1 to use within this component class
    this.func1 = func1.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
       const calc = this.func1(10,20)
       return  /*<div>{calc}</div>*/
  }
}


console.log(new DoSomething().func1(10, 10))// expect 10*10/3 = 33.33..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it reusable like this:

```
import Function1 from './Function

class DoSomething extends Component{

  render(){
    <div>
    <Function1 var1={1} var2={2}</div>

  }
}
```

your Function1 is seperate file as Funtion1.js

```
export default (props) => (  console.log(props); // do anything you want )
```

PS you can also do **named export** here but it depends.